# Selenium - Element not being picked up by xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am having a very hard time getting the simplest **xpath** to work - making me think this is an issue with my set up or I am just not seeing something very obvious.

I am using **NodeJS** with **Chrome**.

Code's below:

```
var selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
var Builder = selenium.Builder;
var By = selenium.By;
var Key = selenium.Key;
var util = selenium.util;
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

(async function example() {
  var driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

  try {
    await driver.get('http://leisurelink.lcsd.gov.hk/?lang=en');
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='formPanelResponsive']/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div"));
  } finally {
    //await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

I get the below error:

```
(node:1261) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='formPanelResponsive']/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div"}
```

What am I missing here? The bit I want to click is **Facility Booking - Basic Version** and I got it's xpath by opening JS console and copying it's xpath.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: It opens up another window. How do I go to that? (It's my next step, I know, but I thought I may as well ask)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the html of the element which you want to access

Comment: Facility Booking - Basic Version - I stated that in my question. Thanks

Comment: The site URL is provided and so is the element I want to select. Precisely this one:

<div onclick="openwin('/application/CheckChannelSuspension.do?applicationId=LCSD_11&amp;language=en&amp;country=US');return false;" onblur="this.className='actionBtnBlock';" onmouseout="this.className='actionBtnBlock';" onfocus="this.className='actionBtnBlock_hover';" onmouseover="this.className='actionBtnBlock_hover';" class="actionBtnBlock">
        Facility Booking - Basic Version 
       </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the element by fetching the element by its text in the xpath and you should apply explicit wait on the element so that the script waits till the element is visible.
You can do it like:

```
await driver.get('http://leisurelink.lcsd.gov.hk/?lang=en');
await driver.sleep(1000);
let el = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Facility Booking - Basic Version')]"));
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(el),100);
await el.click();
```

Comment: Very strange one mate. Also not found: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'Facility Booking - Basic Version')]"}

I also tried it with different wordings but it just doesn't seem to be able to find anything

Comment: @ShayanKhan yeah its happening because the script is not waiting for the element to be visible. I have edited my ans and added explicit wait in it now. Please pick the edited ans

Comment: The same... See below:

(node:2357) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'Facility Booking - Basic Version')]"}

Comment: @ShayanKhan this is strange because i have tried the same code in java and its working fine. Can you try to put some hard wait after hitting the url and then try to access the element by the xpath i have provided

Comment: That did it mate! Do you want edit your answer so I can accept it? I just added a "await driver.sleep(1000);" right after launching the site

Comment: @ShayanKhan Great that it worked, yes i have edited my answer!

Comment: Really appreciate your help! Thanks again